# install java6 and tomcat7 on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7, ubuntu-10.10, java

Ubuntu is running on Amazon EC2, version 10.10

- installed java using

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

(more about openjdk6 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/openjdk-6-jdk)

- did the following to in install tomcat7

> wget -c http://apache.petsads.us/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.27.tar.gz
>
> sudo tar xvfz apache-tomcat-7.0.27.tar.gz -C /var

Then I see a folder called apache-tomcat-7.0.27 under /var

go to /var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin and run：

> sudo bash startup.sh

It looks like tomcat starts successfully:

> ubuntu@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX:/var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin$ sudo bash startup.sh
>
> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27
>
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27
>
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/temp
>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
>
> Using CLASSPATH:       /var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

I did a test by doing:

> sudo fuser -v -n tcp 8080

then i got result(looks like tomcat is up and running):

> 0                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
>
> 8080/tcp:            root       1234 F.... java

But if i type in address of my server in browser, i can't see the default tomcat page...

Am I missing anything????? I am open to any advices.

### I followed some of the steps (not all of them) in **http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-java-stack.html#tomcat**

The solution of this problem is:
This instance is not owned by me. 
I asked my friend to change the rule for 8080 in the firewall configuration via his aws management console.
Then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out knowing exactly what your setup is, my first guess is you need to open port 8080 on the security group for that instance. Go to security groups and either open it to 0.0.0.0/0 or ur specific IP (this depends on your security requirements for the server)